# Parse Serialized String in VB.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am using this jQuery to send serialized form data to my controller action:

```
var data = $('#quiz').serialize();
            //alert(data);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Challenge/GetQuizScore',
                type: 'post',
                data: { data: data },
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function (result) {
                    // update chart

                },
```

Then, I am using this controller to read it:

```
<EmployeeAuthorize()>
<HttpPost()>
Function GetQuizScore(ByVal data As String) As JsonResult

    Debug.Print(data)

    Return Json(data)

End Function
```

The output of data is like this:

> 4=True&5=Exercising+regularly

What's the best way to parse this kind of data so I can use it in my action (preferably loop through it something like this:

```
For Each item in myData

    If (item.value == myArray.value) Then
    ' do something
    Else
    ' do something else
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Try to use: `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;` before you code `$.ajax(...);`.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use the data in context of VB.NET.  I know how to send but not retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `json`

```
 $.ajax({
                url: '/Challenge/GetQuizScore',
                type: 'post',
                data: { data: data },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    // update chart

                },
```

Comment: Thank you, so how do I use the data in VB.NET?